# Jasmine-rails error: has no method 'andCallFake'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, jasmine

Attempting to run some jasmine specs (written in coffeescript), via the jasmine-rails gem, and I'm getting several jasmine errors.  I'm using the `andCallFake()` method at several points in my code, and any specs which contain that method are failing.  All of my other tests pass.  At first I suspected it had something to do with the `jasmine.mock-ajax` library, but attempting to create a spy on a method which doesn't use that library causes the same error.

Example test code (coffee):

```
  it 'should trigger an event on success', ->
    validateSpy = jasmine.createSpy 'validate spy'
    obj.on 'validated', validateSpy
    $.ajax.isSpy = false
    spyOn($, 'ajax').andCallFake(params) ->
      params.success = true
```

And the error message:

```
TypeError: Object function () {
    callTracker.track({
      object: this,
      args: Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)
    });
    return spyStrategy.exec.apply(this, arguments);
  } has no method 'andCallFake'
```

Comment: Turns out jasmine 2.0 removes `andCallFake`

Answer (score 2):

I can spot one error in your test code: you need a space between `andCallFake` and `(params)`
So `andCallFake (params)`

I just tried this on coffeescript.org and you can see the difference

Comment: Right. `f(x) -> ...` is `f(x)(-> ...)` but `f (x) -> ...` is `f((x) -> ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like jasmine 2.0 removes the `andCallFake` method, and we slurped it up with a bundle update. Locking the `jasmine-core` gem down solved the problem.

Comment: Yep, jasmine 2.0 uses .and.CallFake method